# Does a recursive function with infinite domain and a finite range have to be periodic?

Tags: recursion, periodic-functions

I think the answer is yes, but I'm unsure of how to make a rigorous argument. One of the key things that I can think of is the fact that since that map is from infinite to finite at least one of the outputs has to have infinitely many inputs that map to it, meaning that it can't have an inverse. But I'm unsure where to go with that information.

EDIT: To clarify what I mean by recursive function here is this. What I mean, is a set of values $a_n$ for positive integers $n$ defined such that $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$ and $a_0$ equals some constant $c$. My question then is there a function $g$ such the set $g(a_n)$ is infinite, but the set $a_n$ is finite.

Comment: by "cyclical" you mean "periodic"?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I mean. I'll make an edit to reflect that.

Comment: I deleted my answer for now, so please clarify as well as you can your criteria for recursive function, allowed operations etc., so we know exactly what you are struggling with.

Comment: This is still unclear.  $g(a_n)$ is an element of the range of $g$, not a set.  Do you mean the set $\{g(a_0), g(a_1), g(a_2), \ldots \}$?  This set is finite if $\{a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ is finite.

Comment: @A.Goodier the_fox's [edit] corrected the typo ("rigourous") and fixed grammar, and such [minor technical corrections](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10054/290189) are encouraged "without further discussion".  I don't understand why you objected this.

Comment: I do mean ${g(a_0), g(a_1), g(a_2), \dots \}$, I again made another clarity assumption that $a_n$ would be interpretted as all positive integers $n$ with the values of $a_n$ defines by the recursive relationship. The premise of my question is that $\{a_0,a_1,a_2, \dots\}$ is infinite, by being one-to-one with the integers.

Comment: In this case, it will be always cycling, but it need not to be periodic. It will be cycling, because since there are only finitely many values for $a_n$, there must be $n_0 < n_1$ such that $a_{n_0} =a_{n_1} $, therefore $ f(a_{n_0}) = f(a_{n_1}) $, and therefore the evolution of values will repeat itself from the first time the equality  $a_{n_0} =a_{n_1}$ appears, and with period $n_1 - n_0$. However, it might not be periodic, since for instance $a_0 = 1$, and $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 2$. Because of that $1$ on the beginning of the sequence, it is not periodic function on its whole domain.

Comment: Ok, can you come up with any specific examples, or are there not any simple ones?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_k$, $\>k\geq-1$, be the decimal places of $$\sqrt{2}=1.414\ldots=\sum_{k=-1}^\infty a_k\,10^{-k}\ .$$
The sequence $(a_k)_{k\geq-1}$ has finite range $[0\,..\,9]$, but is not ultimately periodic, nor "random". (If this sequence were ultimately periodic $\sqrt{2}$ would be rational.)